# CodeIgniter database error (SUM)

Tags: database, codeigniter

Hello i've problem like this
[image: error]

this is my model:

```
$sql = "SELECT saldo.kode, saldo.nama, SUM(bayar.jmlh_bayar) FROM saldo, bayar WHERE saldo.nama = bayar.akun ORDER BY saldo.nama";
            $result = $this->db->get($sql);
            return $result->result();
```

this is controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $this->load->model('uas/sampah_model');
    $terserah['c']= $this->sampah_model->get();
    //$terserah['kode']=$this->sampah_model->kode();
    $this->load->view('UAS/saldo',$terserah);

}
```

this is my view:

```
<tr>
    <?php
                                          foreach ($c as $item){
                                          echo "<td>";
                                              echo $item->kode;
                                          echo "</td>";
                                          echo "<td>";
                                            echo $item->nama;
                                          echo "</td>";
                                          echo "<td>";
                                            echo $item->jmlh_bayar;
                                          echo "</td>";
                                          echo "<td>";
                                          echo anchor('UAS/utama/hapus/'.$item->kode,'Hapus');   
                                          echo "</td>";
                                          echo  "</tr>";
                                          }
                                          ?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please add the error message in as text, not a picture, so that other people with the same message may be able to find this question in the future and makes it easier to read, in general.
Am I correct that this in PHP?

Comment: learn a lot from this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

whats the point putting `SELECT statements` inside `$this->db_>get()`

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Instead of `get` use `query`

*Your query should be like this :*

```
$sql = "SELECT saldo.kode, saldo.nama, SUM(bayar.jmlh_bayar) 
        FROM saldo, bayar WHERE saldo.nama = bayar.akun 
        ORDER BY saldo.nama";

$result = $this->db->query($sql);
return $result->result();
```

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to upvote and check it as green